# Marklogic Datahub: How to edit the TDEX file and generate the triples?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using Data Hub Quick Start V5.4.0 and Marklogic Version 10.0-6.0

I have a few tdex files in data-hub-FINAL-SCHEMAS.

In the Marklogic console, When I select data-hub-FINAL and execute the SPARQL query:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o}
```

I am able to get the triples in the output.

When I manually update on of the tdex file (In the Marklogic Console) and run the SPARQL query again, I am not able to see the modifications in the generated triples.

Do I need to run any specific function so that triples gets generated by using the updated TDEX file? or
What is the correct procedure to edit the TDEX file and get the updated triples from it?

Following is the procedure I am following to edit the TDEX file:

1. In the Marklogic console, select the database "data-hub-FINAL-SCHEMAS"
2. Click on the Explore button
3. In the bottom window, in the list of files, click on the "ml-data-hub-tde" and this will list out all the TDEX files.
4. Click on the TDEX file which you want to edit
5. Click on EDIT button on the top-right corner of the bottom window.
6. Do the required changes to this file and click on the save button.
7. In the Marklogic console, select the database "data-hub-FINAL"
8. Run the above SPARQL Query to verify the updates to the TDEX in the form of generated triples.

Comment: Make sure you change the qconsole database that you're running the script against back to data-hub-STAGING. My guess is you're getting no data back because you're running the query against the schemas database, not the staging database.